# Executing gsutil command via nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create an application in which json file containing details of request.body gets uploaded in the GCS Bucket.

Before this I simply created a txt file in the same directory as my code and tried to upload that txt file in the gcs bucket once I hit the API ... I was successful in that aspect.

I want to create a json file with content of req.body which i am able to create. Please find the below screen shot:
[json gets created as soon as I hit the api via Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLspg.png)

Problem is my gsutil command is not working .... Please help

Below is my app.js code

````
const path = require('path');
const app = express(),
      bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
      fs = require('fs'),
      port = 8080;
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');
const customCss = fs.readFileSync((process.cwd()+"/swagger.css"), 'utf8');

const { exec } = require('child_process');



var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
month = (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month;
var day = date.getDate();
day = (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
var filename = 'ddr_requests_' + date.getFullYear() + '_' + month + '_' + day + '.json';


app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, {customCss}));

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.send(`<h1>API Running on port ${port}</h1>`);
});

app.put('/api/ddr/:ticket_id', (req, res) => {
    const ticket_id = req.params.ticket_id;
    const requestBody = req.body;
    if(!requestBody || !ticket_id){
        res.status(404).send({message: 'There is an error'});
    }
    var fs = require('fs');
    var writer = fs.createWriteStream(filename,{ 'flags': 'a'
    , 'encoding': null
    , 'mode': 0666
    });
    writer.write(JSON.stringify(requestBody)+','); 
    exec('gsutil -m cp -r ./'+filename+' gs://gibberish/'+ date.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day + '/', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error');
        return;
      }
      // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  });
    res.status(201).send('all ok');
  });
  
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on the port::::::${port}`);
});```
````

Comment: What does **my gsutil command is not working** mean? Clearly specify what does not work and include error messages.

Comment: there is only one gsutil command in the code ..... gsutil -m cp -r ./'+filename+' gs://gibberish/'+ date.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day + '/'

Comment: OK - but what does not work mean? Reread my first comment. We do not have crystal balls to see the error message or unexpected results. You must post that information.